# Is it possible to let airdrop send files to multiple devices at the same time?

Tags: ios, iphone, airdrop

I'm building file transferrer app and I want to use Airdrop's feature to send to multiple recipent at the same time is that possible.
If not what are my options?

Answer (score 2):

Airdrop only allows users to select one recipient at a time.